# CSS flex layout and intruding footer issue

Tags: html, flexbox, angular-material

I started my adventure with flex (Angular Material version to be precise) and approached a difficult problem to solve. Basically I would have a cake and eat the cake :) So I wish my footer was always in the bottom but in the small resolutions while page is very short, I would like avoid floating by footer over main content and not setting hard height for the content.

My page markup is like:

```
<body>
   <ui-view layout="column" layout-fill>
       <md-toolbar>top menu</md-toolbar>
       <div class="main-content" layout="row" flex layout-fill>
           <md-sidenav flex="15" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">left menu</md-sidenav>
           <md-content flex>page content</md-content>
       </div>
       <footer>footer</footer>
   </ui-view>
</body>
```

Comment: You should post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do I understand you correct with this solution? ... and when content exceed the viewport it pushes either the footer down and all page will scroll

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;           /*  IE 11/10 min-height bug fix  */
}
ui-view {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
md-sidenav {
  background: lightgray;
}
md-content {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <ui-view layout="column" layout-fill>
       <md-toolbar>top menu</md-toolbar>
       <div class="main-content" layout="row" flex layout-fill>
           <md-sidenav flex="15" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">left menu</md-sidenav>
           <md-content flex>
             page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content
         </md-content>
       </div>
       <footer>footer</footer>
   </ui-view>
</body>
```

or the `main-content` starts to scroll

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;           /*  IE 11/10 min-height bug fix  */
}
ui-view {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.main-content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightgray;
}
md-sidenav {
  width: 120px;
}
md-content {
  background: lightgreen;
  flex: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <ui-view layout="column" layout-fill>
       <md-toolbar>top menu</md-toolbar>
       <div class="main-content" layout="row" flex layout-fill>
           <md-sidenav flex="15" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">left menu</md-sidenav>
           <md-content flex>
             <div class="wrapper">
             page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content <br> page content 
             </div>
           </md-content>
       </div>
       <footer>footer</footer>
   </ui-view>
</body>
```